# The catalog inventory stock item unique hase changed

Tags: magento2, stock, cataloginventory

I am working on a new Magento 2.1.4 projet. We have a single store. And we need to manage the inventory for a large amount of shops belonging to this store.

I was thinking about using the cataloginventory_stock tables. We did it on a Magento 1.x version. But since Magento 2, the unique index of the cataloginventory_stock_item table has changed. It is now on the product_id and website_id. Which allow only one line of stock per product and website.
In version 1.x the unique index was on product_id and stock_id which would be more suitable.

Is this a bug that the stock_id disapeared from the cataloginventory_stock_item? Or is it something planned?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have been to quick to post questions here. This is a bug. I checked https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1002.

Sorry for disturbance!!